# How to read a complete file with scanf maybe something like %[^\EOF] without loop in single statement

Tags: c, file, scanf, eof

I want to know if I can read a complete file with single scanf statement. I read it with below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char arr[200],fmt[6]="%[^";
    fp = fopen("testPrintf.c","r");
    fmt[3] = EOF;
    fmt[4] = ']';
    fmt[5] = '\0';
    fscanf(fp,fmt,arr);
    printf("%s",arr);
    printf("%d",EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

And it resulted into a statement after everything happened

"* * * stack smashing detected * * *:  terminated
Aborted (core dumped)"

Interestingly, printf("%s",arr); worked but printf("%d",EOF); is not showing its output.

Can you let me know what has happened when I tried to read upto EOF with scanf?

Comment: `EOF` is not a character you can match with `scanf`'s `%[...]` directive. (Nice try, though.)

Comment: If the file is bigger than 200 bytes, you're obviously going to have problems reading it into `arr`.

Comment: Is this some kind of challenge where practicality doesn't matter?  If you want to read the whole file, `fscanf` is totally not the right tool for the job.  (I'd use either `getc` or `fread`.)

Comment: Yes, it practically doesn't matter :) 
Yes totally correct with small file its not showing that statement. Thanks Steve

Comment: But why that error does not appear while scanf and did appear only when printf completely worked?

Comment: Why would you use `scanf` and not `fread` for this??

Comment: So `testPrintf.c` is, by my count, 254 bytes long, and obviously 254 is greater than 200.  So if you write (or if you cause `scanf` to write) 254 bytes to `arr[]`, you've scribbled on 54 bytes you don't own, and the question is, what problem is that going to cause, and when? If it doesn't cause a problem immediately, then `printf` is able to read the 254 bytes (including reading 54 bytes from memory not allocated to `arr[]`, but `printf` doesn't know that).  The problem likely doesn't get detected until `main` returns, and some supervisor notices that the stack frame is damaged.

Comment: To expand on R's comment above, fscanf() is the wrong tool for this job.  Call stat() to find the file size, malloc() the amount of needed space, and fread() into it.  But this is really only a solution for small files--make sure you check the return from malloc() to catch failures to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really must (ab)use [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) into reading the file, then this outlines how you could do it:

- open the file
- use [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) and 
  [`ftell()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html) to find the size of the file
- [`rewind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) (or `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)`) to reset the file to the start
- allocate a big buffer
- create a format string that reads the correct number of bytes into the buffer and records how many characters are read
- use the format with `fscanf()`
- add a null terminating byte in the space reserved for it
- print the file contents as a big string.

If there are no null bytes in the file, you'll see the file contents printed. If there are null bytes in the file, you'll see the file contents up to the first null byte.

I chose the anodyne name `data` for the file to be read — there are endless ways you can make that selectable at runtime.

There are a few assumptions made about the size of the file (primarily that the size isn't bigger than can be fitted into a `long` with signed overflow, and that it isn't empty).  It uses the fact that the `%c` format can accept a length, just like most of the formats can, and it doesn't add a null terminator at the end of the string it reads and it doesn't fuss about whether the characters read are null bytes or anything else — it just reads them.  It also uses the fact that you can specify the size of the variable to hold the offset with the `%n` (or, in this case, the `%ln`) conversion specification.  And finally, it assumes that the file is not shrinking (it will ignore growth if it is growing), and that it is a seekable file, not a FIFO or some other special file type that does not support seeking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "data";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long length = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    char *buffer = malloc(length + 1);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %ld bytes\n", length + 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char format[32];
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ldc%%ln", length);
    long nbytes = 0;
    if (fscanf(fp, format, buffer, &nbytes) != 1 || nbytes != length)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read %ld bytes (got %ld)\n", length, nbytes);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    printf("<<<SOF>>\n%s\n<<EOF>>\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return(0);
}
```

This is still an abuse of `fscanf()` — it would be better to use `fread()`:

```
    if (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, fp) != (size_t)length)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read %ld bytes\n", length);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You can then omit the variable `format` and the code that sets it, and also `nbytes`.  Or you can keep `nbytes` (maybe as a `size_t` instead of `long`) and assign the result of `fread()` to it, and use the value in the error report, along the lines of the test in the `fscanf()` variant.

You might get warnings from GCC about a non-literal format string for `fscanf()`.  It's correct, but this isn't dangerous because the programmer is completely in charge of the content of the format string.

Comment: Why `fseek`/`ftell` to find the size?  Is that considered less nonportable than `stat`?

Comment: The original code didn’t hint at using `stat()` so I stuck with standard C.  Using `stat()` is feasible; it isn’t much more compact than futzing with `fseek()` and `ftell()`. At extremely large file sizes in 32-bit programs, `stat()` may be better.